# Kendo UI MVVM - Changing Model not firing DataSource change event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have a Grid bound to a DataSource via MVVM.

I select a row in the Grid, accordingly I use this:

```
var grid = e.sender;
var rowSelected = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
this.set("currentAccount", rowSelected);
```

Where "currentAccount" holds the currently selected row. Also, "currentAccount" is bound to a Form to be edited by user.

Now, when I do changes on the form fields, they are not being automatically reflected on Grid. I need to call grid.refresh() for the changes to show on grid. With further debugging, I noticed that the datasource defined inside the viewmodel and that is used for Grid, is not firing it's Change event!

However, when user presses a button "Add new record", the following is used to create a new empty model inside the datasource, setting this new model returned by .add() function to be the "currentAccount":

```
var newRow = this.get("accRegDatasource").add( this._makeAccountModel( 0 ) ); 
this.set("currentAccount", newRow); 
var row = input_map.grid().find(" tr[data-uid='" + newRow.uid + "']"); 
input_map.kendoGrid().select(row);
```

Above, I am adding a new empty row. Once I start editing the Form fields, automatically they are being reflected on the Grid without having to call grid.refresh. Even the datasource defined in the viewmodel is firing it's change event.

Any idea why this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like some of the objects that you update is not instance of the ObservableObject. Please demonstrate your case with a small demo so we can check.

Comment: Here you go: http://dojo.telerik.com/upiPE/26

Comment: Didn't I answer similar question on the kendo forums?